# change text colors in a PHP file using CSS

Tags: php, css, arrays, text

i have a PHP array that prints info and i need to print each line using different
color using external CSS.

i tried writing

```
$color = 'red';
```

in the PHP file and

```
body
{
color: <?=$color?>;
}
```

in the external CSS
but it doesn't work,also tried the '#' . $color?;
and still can't get it to work.

any tips will be appreciated

Comment: You need to provide some more information about your code. Paste your code here.

Comment: You can't use php in your css. I suggest creating some classes in css for the different colours you want and then putting those classes on the elements that you need to be a specific colour.

Comment: PHP code is only parsed if the file extension matchs .php , .php3 . phtml, .php5 etc. It will not be executed inside a external file with .css extension. One more thing, a variable's value is only accessible inside the script where it was defined, so just echoing it anywhere will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If I have guessed it right then you are actually trying to use a PHP variable inside a .css file but unfortunately, it will not work as your php parser will not parse that variable because it simply ignore any files with any extensions other than .php, .phtml, .php3, .php4 and i guess there are couple of more extensions for php files.